# Azure Active Directory Web Application without login current user

Tags: azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity, adal, directoryservices

I am following an older tutorial (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Write-Sample-App-for-79e55502) that shows how to create a web application that connects to an Azure Active Directory tenant using ADAL. There is a class library that contains DirectoryService classes that I believe does the work in retrieving AD user properties. I am wanting to create a login method for this project for security purposes, and to be able to identify what user is logged in to the application. Currently there is not a signin method that authenticates against AD by entering a username/password, so I am a little puzzled at how the app can retrieve user properties with just the AppId,Domain,and AppSecret in the Web.config without actually having someone login with either their AD creds or redirecting to login.microsoftonline/{tenantId}.....I do not know if I am making sense, but I want to be able to add a login method so a user is forced to login so it gets the claims for that specific user but if I am already using ADAL, can I also incorporate Owin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to your question -

**1. How is this app working today, without asking end users to explicitly sign in**

This sample is using Client Credential Grant, in which you don't need end users to sign in, but use the identity of an application itself to get the auth token and use it for further operations. As you mention yourself, it just needs AppId, Domain and App Secret from web.config. You can read all about it here - [Client Credentials Grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)

Related code to acquire token is available in MVCDirectoryGraphSample\Helpers\MVCGraphServiceHelper.cs file

```
  AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString); 
                ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppPrincipalId"],
```

**2. How to add a login method to force users to sign in to your web application**

You can start using something like Authorization Code Grant flow, instead of client credentials. Look here for documentation on different [scenarios that Azure AD supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-scenarios). Your case looks like a web application calling Graph API, described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-scenarios#web-application-to-web-api)

Exact code sample to do this is available here - [Code Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v1-code#web-applications)

Comment: Thanks for the response and shedding some light. Can two authentication methods be used? The client credential grant takes care of authenticating the application based on the Tenant the app is registered through as I understand it. If I was wanting to also include a login for users that will be using the application that authenticates the user by having them sign into their Microsoft Work Account, would it mess anything up with the client credential grant by adding a reference to Owin and implementing OpenIdConnect to get the user claim id and name?

Comment: I know I can probably just grant access to users on an individual basis since not many users will be using it but since it contains AD user info, I am trying to lock it down. I do not understand the authentication too much, but I have not found a way to implement both authentication by client credential grant AND Owin context authentication yet.

Comment: I think I got your requirement, but correct me if I go wrong. End user >> Web Application (force user sign in thru Authorization code grant flow). Web Application >> Graph API or any other API for that matter (client credential grant flow using config entries like in sample). Both should work fairly independent if you pass token acquired using client credentials to next API. It's definitely doable, start with code using samples I shared.. if you get stuck open a new question with specific details/issues you face, that way I/others can help you better. Comments rarely get enough attention :)